# Identify changes in rows when merging two dataframs

Tags: r, reshape2

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("AAPL", 
"GOOG", "IBM"), class = "factor"), Price.X = c(150L, 139L, NA
), Price.Y = c(NA, 120L, 1200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))


structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("AAPL", 
"GOOG", "IBM"), class = "factor"), Price.X = c(150L, 139L, NA
), Price.Y = c(NA, 120L, 1200L), Status = structure(3:1, .Label = c("Added", 
"Control", "Removed"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Above is a short example of a database I have. I am trying to track changes in a list between years, so I merged two years, getting Price.X and Price.Y, where Price.Y is the newer year.

The result I'm trying to get is having a new column, Status, to indicate whether or not it is added, removed, or constant (control). I tried using if then statements. Given the structure of the data, if a stock has Price.X is NA and Price.Y is numeric, then it's added. If Price.Y is NA and Price.X is numeric, then it's removed. The other case is control by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `dplyr` and `case_when`?

You can modify each scenario as appropriate. `TRUE` at the end is the catch-all here.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Status = case_when(
    is.na(Price.Y) ~ "Removed",
    is.na(Price.X) ~ "Added",
    TRUE ~ "Control"
  ))

  Name Price.X Price.Y  Status
1 AAPL     150      NA Removed
2  IBM     139     120 Control
3 GOOG      NA    1200   Added
```